# XSLT- Jump from table to table in the same page by clicking on table entries

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I am new to HTML, XML & XSLT, I am trying to convert XML to HTML by using XSLT. While I can make it work, however, I am stuck with allowing user to jump from table to table according to some of the table entries, all of the tables are in 1 single page. For example,

[image]

For simplicity's sake, I have removed other tables besides than the tables used in the example above
XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="style.xsl"?>
<root>
<configType name="VipMobile_SOAP_BasicOrderRequestType" extends="VipMobile_SOAP">
    <version major="1" minor="0" branded="true"/>
    <fields>
        <field id="ExternalBusinessTransactionID" type="string"/>
        <field id="orderRequest" type="reference" reftype="VipMobile_SOAP_orderRequestType"/>
    </fields>
</configType>
<!-- com.tibco.aff.order.OrderRequestType -->
<configType name="VipMobile_SOAP_orderRequestType" extends="VipMobile_SOAP">
    <version major="1" minor="0" branded="true"/>
    <fields>
        <field id="extension" type="reference" reftype="VipMobile_SOAP_extensionType"/>
        <field id="header" type="reference" reftype="VipMobile_SOAP_headerRequestType"/>
        <field id="line" type="reference" reftype="VipMobile_SOAP_lineRequestType" multiValued="true"/>
        <field id="orderRef" type="string"/>
    </fields>
</configType>
</root>
```

My XSLT stylesheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/root">
  <html>
  <body>
    <xsl:for-each select="configType">
        <table border="2">
          <p><font color="#404040" face="verdana" ><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></font></p>
          <p><font color="#404040" face="verdana" size="2"> extends  <xsl:value-of select="@extends"/></font></p>
          <tr bgcolor="#0059b3">
            <th style="text-align:left"><font color="#ffffff" face="verdana"> Attribute Name</font></th>
            <th style="text-align:left"><font color="#ffffff" face="verdana"> Attribute Type</font></th>
            <th style="text-align:left"><font color="#ffffff" face="verdana"> Description</font></th>
          </tr>
          <xsl:for-each select="fields/field">
          <tr  bgcolor="#3399ff">
            <td><font color="#ffffff" face="verdana"><xsl:value-of select="@id"/></font></td>
            <td><font color="#ffffff" face="verdana"><xsl:value-of select="@type"/></font></td>
            <td><a href="#{@reftype}"><font face="verdana"><xsl:value-of select="@reftype"/></font></a></td>
          </tr>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What I have tried

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/root">
  <html>
  <body>
    <xsl:for-each select="configType">
        <table border="2">
          <p><font color="#404040" face="verdana" ><a name="{generate-id(@name)}"><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></a></font></p>
          <p><font color="#404040" face="verdana" size="2"> extends  <xsl:value-of select="@extends"/></font></p>
          <tr bgcolor="#0059b3">
            <th style="text-align:left"><font color="#ffffff" face="verdana"> Attribute Name</font></th>
            <th style="text-align:left"><font color="#ffffff" face="verdana"> Attribute Type</font></th>
            <th style="text-align:left"><font color="#ffffff" face="verdana"> Description</font></th>
          </tr>
          <xsl:for-each select="fields/field">
          <tr  bgcolor="#3399ff">
            <td><font color="#ffffff" face="verdana"><xsl:value-of select="@id"/></font></td>
            <td><font color="#ffffff" face="verdana"><xsl:value-of select="@type"/></font></td>
            <td><a href="#{generate-id(/root/configType/@name)}"><font face="verdana"><xsl:value-of select="@reftype"/></font></a></td>
          </tr>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was very simple

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/root">
  <html>
  <body>
    <xsl:for-each select="configType">
        <table border="2">
          <p><font color="#404040" face="verdana" ><a name="{@name}"><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></a></font></p>
          <p><font color="#404040" face="verdana" size="2"> extends  <xsl:value-of select="@extends"/></font></p>
          <tr bgcolor="#0059b3">
            <th style="text-align:left"><font color="#ffffff" face="verdana"> Attribute Name</font></th>
            <th style="text-align:left"><font color="#ffffff" face="verdana"> Attribute Type</font></th>
            <th style="text-align:left"><font color="#ffffff" face="verdana"> Description</font></th>
          </tr>
          <xsl:for-each select="fields/field">
          <tr  bgcolor="#3399ff">
            <td><font color="#ffffff" face="verdana"><xsl:value-of select="@id"/></font></td>
            <td><font color="#ffffff" face="verdana"><xsl:value-of select="@type"/></font></td>
            <td><a href="#{@reftype}"><font face="verdana"><xsl:value-of select="@reftype"/></font></a></td>
          </tr>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```